# Pointer increment difference b/w 32-bit and 64-bit

Tags: winapi, 32bit-64bit, wdk

I was trying to run some drivers coded for 32-bit vista (x86) on 64-bit win7 (amd64) and it was not running. After a lot of debugging, and hit-and-trial, I made it to work on the latter, but I don't know the reason why it's working. This is what I did:

At many places, buffer pointers pointed to an array of structures(different at different places), and to increment them, at some places this type of statement was used:

```
ptr = (PVOID)((PCHAR)ptr + offset);
```

And at some places:

```
ptr = (PVOID)((ULONG)ptr + offset);
```

The 2nd one was returning garbage, so I changed them all to 1st one. But I found many sample drivers on the net following the second one. My questions:

1. Where are these macros
   defined(google didn't help much)?
2. I understand all the P_ macros are
   pointers, why was a pointer casted
   to ULONG? How does this work on
   32-bit?
3. PCHAR obviously changes the
   width according to the environment. Do you know any place to find documentation for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. they should be defined in WinNT.h (they are in the SDK; don't have the DDK at hand)
2. ULONG is unsigned long; on a 32-bit system, this is the size of a pointer. So a pointer
   can be converted back and forth to ULONG without loss - but not so on a 64-bit system
   (where casting the value will truncate it). People cast to ULONG to get byte-base pointer 
   arithmetic (even though this has undefined behavior, as you found out)
3. Pointer arithmetic always works in units of the underlying type, i.e. in CHARs for PCHAR; this equates to bytes arithmetic
4. Any C book should elaborate on the precise semantics of pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 3):

The reason this code fails on 64-bit is that it is casting pointers to ULONG. ULONG is a 32-bit value while pointers on 64-bit are 64-bit values. So you will be truncating the pointer whenever you use the ULONG cast.

The PCHAR cast, assuming PCHAR is defined as `char *` is fine, provided the intention is to increment the pointer by an explicit number of bytes.

Both macros have the same intention but only one of them is valid where pointers are larger than 32-bits.

Pointer arithmetic works like this. If you have:

```
T *p;
```

and you do:

```
p + n;
```

(where n is a number), then the value of p will change by `n * sizeof(T)`.

To give a concrete example, if you have a pointer to a DWORD:

```
DWORD *pdw = &some_dword_in_memory;
```

and you add one to it:

```
pdw = pdw + 1;
```

then you will be pointing to the next DWORD. The address pdw points to will have increased by `sizeof(DWORD)`, i.e. 4 bytes.

The macros you mention are using casts to cause the address offsets they apply to be multiplied by different amounts. This is normally only done in low-level code which has been passed a BYTE (or char or void) buffer but knows the data inside it is really some other type.

Comment: Re-reading your question, I noticed it was casting to ULONG not ULONG*, so I added the part at the top of my answer, which I think is the most important part. The rest is just background info.

Answer (score 1):

[`ULONG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa505945.aspx) is defined in WinDef.h in Windows SDK and is always 32-bit, so when you cast a 64-bit pointer into `ULONG` you truncate the pointer to 32 bits.